# ASP.NET and IIS7 Winsock Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have recently setup a new development PC, which is 64 bit and has IIS 7.  I am developing a web application, which I would regularly deploy to my old development PC.  On my new development PC, I am prompted with the following error:

```
[SocketException (0x273b): The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists]
System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6, Boolean throwOnFailure) +1576906
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(String address) +117
_Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +154
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

I have debugged the error and I have traced it to the following line:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName
```

If I comment out this line, then it works perfectly.  What is the problem with this line?

Comment: What is returned by the call to Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")?

Comment: @mj, thanks.  This returns: :1, which is also unusual.

Comment: I think that's your part of your problem then. Try hard coding in an IP. CNN.com is 157.166.255.19 and see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetHostByAddress is obsolete now use GetHostEntry, please check below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dat0fbe2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: is it IIS7 that makes it obselete?

Comment: Please check this link of Obsolete members http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee471421.aspx

Comment: what do you mean? I have marked the question as answered.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: :) you can see above the tick mark '0' is between Up & Down arrow, Up arrow means Up Vote & Down arrow means down vote. Up vote means it was helpful and Down vote means not related to topic.

Comment: When you take Mouse over the UP and DOWN arrows you will see tooltip

Comment: I understand how to upvote, however I am asking 'what?' do you want me to upvote.  Isn't answering the question enough?