# How to force VisualStudio to do a check for .Net Service Pack compatibility?

Tags: .net, compatibility, missingmethodexception

When .Net service pack is released, some new classes may be extended with new methods.

One of such methods is WaitHandle.WaitOne(int timeout) method that exists only since .Net 2.0 SP2.

When developers write the code they don't reda MSDN sometimes (especially for something they know enough), or don't look it thoroughly enough, but rather just use intellisense to select method from a dropdown box (because they have .Net 2.0 sp2 installed).

A program then can throw MethodMissingException on computers with Framework 2.0 without SP2. Knowing about such incompatibility in advance could help to avoid this problem.

Is it possible to somehow force Visual Studio (2010) to verify compatibility level of Framwork's Service Pack? Maybe any plug-ins are there?
I hoped Resharper can do this, but it seems it cannot.

**EDIT**:
What I want is that If the code should be .Net SP1 compatible, then compiler or plugin will warn developer if he tries to use method or class that exists only in SP2.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by: verify compatibility level of Framwork's Service Pack?

Comment: I mean If the code should be .Net SP1 compatible, then compiler or plugin will warn developer if he tries yo use method or class that exists only in SP2.

Comment: That was a mistake.  There's no way to protect yourself against it.  .NET 4 has specific countermeasures to prevent this from happening the future, the reference assemblies are no longer a copy of the runtime assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

When you compiler a .net application to target a specific version of a framework, the application will not run at all on older version.

If you try to compile a .NET application on a machine that has an older/newer version of the framework in which methods are missing, the compiler will catch such errors.

Could you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to have developers check that the code is .Net-2.0-with-no-Service-Pack-compatible before they do a code check-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark a function using the obsolete tag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) then you can put in a warning message for the developer e.g. "Use function a instead of function b".

Have a look at this question, which I asked: [ASP.NET and IIS7 Winsock Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141757/asp-net-and-iis7-winsock-error).  I was unable to use 'GetHostByAddress', because it is obselete.